# components not rendered after Vaadin 22 -> 23 upgrade

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm upgrading a Vaadin 22 app to Vaadin 23.
The Vaadin 22 app had some stylesheets, I've put these in `/frontend/themes/mytheme` and using the `@Theme` annotation. This is all working fine, so at least some part of the frontend bundle compilation is working.

The problem is that standard Vaadin components are not being rendered, such as `VaadinIcon` (`<vaadin-icon>`) and `ComboBox` instances.
I've checked and at least the `<vaadin-icon>` elements have a width (24x24) so the problem isn't that they are zero size. I've tried changing the color, so it's not that they are have the same foreground & background color either.

I've tried executing vaadinClean and vaadinPrepareFrontend multiple times (not yet using production mode), also manually deleting the generated files. Nothing helps. What can be the issue? How can I further debug this?

Comment: Are _all_ vaadin components not working? The tags are there and everything else works, so it seems like the registration of the custom elements is not done for the vaadin provided web components? Any errors in the dev-console of the browser? Are you building with vite or do you force the predecessor?  Are the files under `node_modules` for e.g. the combo-box fine?

Comment: Typically running mvn vaadin:clean-frontend and doing build again should help.

Comment: @cfrick I've tested with a few components:
- `Button`, `Routerlink`, `ListBox` are shown (but no icon on the buttons)
- `TextField` is not shown
- `ComboBox` and `DatePicker` are not show shown, and apparently when I add these, I get errors in the debug console: 

```
home:7 The error has occurred in the JS code: '$0, window.Vaadin.Flow.datepickerConnector.initLazy($0)'

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initLazy')
    at Object.eval (eval at Gu (FlowClient.js:1090:101), <anonymous>:3:40)
```

Comment: @TatuLund I'm using Gradle and have executed task vaadinClean multiple times.

Comment: Please remove all folders generated at build time. Also with maven not everything is cleaned up